# Developing Maven 3.0 Plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I have developed few Maven plugins for Maven 2, but I am wondering what are the main changes when I want to develop a plugin (or migrate the existing ones) for Maven 3.0.

The documentation on the Maven site in not up-to-date (*what a surprise!*) and all related pages still deal with Maven 2.0, like this [one](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html):

> This guide is intended to assist users
>   in developing Java plugins for Maven
>   2.0.

As an example, in Maven 2 plugin, I defined a configuration parameter like this:

```
/**
 * Some parameter.
 * 
 * @parameter
 * @required
 */
private String foo;
```

So now, using the new Maven Plugin API, I expect *real* Java annotations...

Question: Where can I find documentation / information about the development of **Maven 3** plugins?

Comment: a) *I expect real Java annotations* I have been expecting them for years :-) b) where's the question

Comment: @Sean Edited, to hightlight the real question...

Comment: Since real documentation is OK to develop a maven 3 plugin, you can get detailed information from my [post](http://sercanozdemir.com/2015/02/maven-3-plugin-development/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a work-in-progress implementation of annotations for Maven plugins developments! Read the following links:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+5+Annotations+for+Plugins
- http://olamy.blogspot.fr/2012/05/java5-annotations-support-for-maven.html

Comment: Annotations support in maven plugins has been released now :-)

Answer (score 4):

for the record you can have a look http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html

Answer (score 2):

Just saw this... maybe it's helpful.

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/11/whats-in-maven-3-0-for-plugin-authors/

Answer (score 2):

I think the best source is http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/index.html
Maybe it is not up to date but it is the best choice in my oppinion.

For developing maven plugins see section 11.

I hope it was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it can be useful for other peoples. On my side, I know how to develop Maven 2 plugins, but my question was to know if Maven 3 introduced new features regarding the development of plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is still relevant but this plugin provides annotation support

[Maven Anno Mojo](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/OSS/Maven+Anno+Mojo)

Answer (score 1):

In meantime the official doc seems to be up to date:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

(they use annotations everywhere)

Answer (score -2):

This is the best I have been able to find regarding plugin development.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Often the best way to work with maven is to use the archetype and play around with that.

Comment: the example on that page doesn't even compile